# Install Jenkins manually on docker image

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to install/run jenkins manually without pulling the Jenkins image from the docker-hub

for this exercise I have used the ubuntu image container and I did the following:

- Install jdk-11 on the container
- Set up the `JAVA_HOME` env variable
- Install jenkins with apt-get
- Run jenkins with the command `service jenkins start`

then status output is the following

```
root@42024442b87b:/# service jenkins status
Correct java version found
Jenkins Automation Server is running with the pid 89
```

Now I don't now how to access the jenkins server running in the container from my host.

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to map the ports when you start the container, see https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: As f1sh said you have to map the ports with -p 8080 in your docker command, then you can use a browser to go to http://localhost:8080 and the secret code you need is in the Jenkins log file

Comment: As you've described this, you're going to lose work as soon as the container exits; that Jenkins installation will be lost.  You should write the setup commands into a Dockerfile and use `docker build` to reproducibly build an image.  Remember that `service` basically doesn't work in Docker; the image's `CMD` will need to run the Jenkins server as a foreground process.

Comment: @f1sh indeed that what I was missing, docker do not expose the containers ports to the host by default, please add your comment as a response to this question so I can accept it.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes indeed I have lost  all installed components when I exited  the container, however I found that to persist the changes on a container `docker commit` works very well to save the changes on a new image.

Comment: How will you recreate that image when there's a security issue in Jenkins in a year, and you _must_ recreate it or have your entire infrastructure compromised?  `docker commit` is pretty much never a best practice.

Comment: @guru I have written my comment as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers are not reachable using the network from the host system by default. You need to expose a container's host, meaning that the port will be opened on the host machine and all traffic forwarded to the container.

Running docker with `-p 8080:8080` forwards 8080. Take a look at the syntax [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

You can also specify which port on the host machine is supposed to be mapped to a container's port with something like `-p 1234:8080`.

You can also use the `EXPOSE` keyword in your `Dockerfile`.